# Creating a Box inside the GUI using tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

My GUI currently looks like this:

[image: So my GUI currently looks like this]

What I'm trying to do is make it look better. By creating Two boxes, one for personal details and one for booking information.

[image: Like this]

What would be the best way to do this? I tried use canvas but that wont work since i'm using grids for text and buttons.

Comment: The use of grid has no bearing on whether or not you can use a canvas. Though, an canvas isn't likely the right tool for this job anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The typical way to do this is to use a [LabelFrame](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/labelframe.htm). Create one for each section, and put the appropriate widgets in each frame. This is exactly why `Frame` and `LabelFrame` exist -- to provide a way to organize widgets into logical groups.

For example:

```
customer_frame = tk.LabelFrame(parent, text="Customer Details", pady=20)
booking_frame = tk.LabelFrame(parent, text="Booking Details", pady=20)
...

# customer inputs
first_label = tk.Label(customer_frame, text="First Name:")
first_entry = tk.Entry(customer_frame)
...

# booking inputs
first_label = tk.Label(booking_frame, text="First Name:")
first_entry = tk.Entry(booking_frame)
...
```